Updating from 8.2.0 to 10.2.1 breaks custom tile load function with cache
Context: I have an extended VectorTileSource class that changes the tileLoadFunction for a custom one. This new function uses a cache to store the tiles and serve them is already loaded. Also when a tile is loaded all pbfs for that tile in diferent instants are preloaded and saved to the cache. This preload is done in order to avoid the blinking effect that happens when a new tile is visualized for the first time.
Issue: When updating openlayers version from 8.2.0 to 10.2.1 this preload part breaks and the blinking appears again when visualizing a tile for the first time.
Code:
export class VectorTileSourceWithCache extends VectorTileSource {
    constructor (options: Options) {
        super(options);
        this.tileLoadFunction = this.tileLoadFunctionWithCache.bind(this);
    }

    private async preloadAllInstances (baseUrl: string, tile: any, extent: Extent, projection: ProjectionLike): Promise<void> {
        const vectorTileStore = useVectorTileStore();
        // Get the instants to preload
        const instants = [/*array of instants*/];
        const urls: string[] = [];
        for (const instant of instants) {
            // Build url for instant
            const url = "url";
            urls.push(url);
        }

        vectorTileStore.addUlrsToPreloadQueue(urls, tile, extent, projection);
    }

    private tileLoadFunctionWithCache (tile: any, url: string): void {
        const vectorTileStore = useVectorTileStore();
        tile.setLoader(async (extent: Extent, _resolution: number, projection: ProjectionLike) => {
            if (!vectorTileStore.isTileInProductBounds(url)) {
                tile.setFeatures([] as Array<Feature<Geometry>>);
            } else if (vectorTileStore.isTileLoaded(url)) {
                const data = vectorTileStore.getDataByUrl(url);
                if (data) {
                    const format = tile.getFormat() as MVT;
                    const features = format.readFeatures(data, {
                        extent,
                        featureProjection: projection as any
                    });
                    tile.setFeatures(features as Array<Feature<Geometry>>);
                } else {
                    tile.setFeatures([] as Array<Feature<Geometry>>);
                }
            } else {
                console.log("PBF not found, requesting...");
                // Fetch tile data if not cached
                try {
                    const response = await axios.get(url, { responseType: "arraybuffer" });
                    if (response.status !== 200) {
                        tile.setFeatures([] as Array<Feature<Geometry>>);
                    } else {
                        const data = response.data;
                        const format = tile.getFormat() as MVT;
                        const features = format.readFeatures(data, {
                            extent,
                            featureProjection: projection as any
                        });
                        tile.setFeatures(features as Array<Feature<Geometry>>);
                        vectorTileStore.addFeatures(url, data, format, extent, projection);
                    }
                } catch (error) {
                    console.error("Error loading tile:", error);
                }
            }
            await this.preloadAllInstances(url, tile, extent, projection);
        });
    }
}

Examples:
Without blinking (openayers verion 8.2.0)
With blinking (openayers verion 10.2.1)
Updating to 10.2.1 typescript throws typing errors. Fixing them don't seem to resolve the problem.I don't know what changes between v8.2.0 and v10.2.1 provoke this or if it has something to do with this issue.

Probably due to this commit https://github.com/openlayers/openlayers/pull/15905/commits/0ab5cb61cc7d84aafc103e0df5f087bb377c7a52 for version 10.0.0 which caches tiles on the layer, and only maintains a small cache on the source

I don't see how this would affect my cache. I preload the tiles and save them outside the source nor the layer. Then when the url changes it should swap tiles with the ones loaded, thing that it does but previously there wasn't any blink inbetween. I am missing any configuration or something?
